# Assign two discrete tasks to a single button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, reset

First of all, is this possible?

I have a reset button in my form and I want to get the text in the input before clicking on the reset button.

```
<form action="Pros.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ordID">Email address:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ordID">
  </div>
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If this is possible, how can I do it?
Thank you.

Comment: Where do you `I want to get the text in the input before clicking`? Where is the input field? What have you tried?

Comment: so sounds like you need to bind a click event....

Comment: @showdev Sorry added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onreset` event handler

```js
function myFunction() {
  var m = document.getElementById('ordID').value;
  console.log(m)
}
```

```html
<form action="Pros.php" method="post" onreset="myFunction()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ordID">Email address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="ordID">
  </div>
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use javascript/jQuery to grab the contents of the input field(s) before you clear them. Here's a basic example:

```js
$('#btnReset').click(function(){
  var ordID = $('#ordID').val();
  alert(ordID);
  $('#ordID').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="Pros.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ordID">Email address:</label>
    <input id="ordID" type="text" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <button id="btnReset" type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
  <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your time